# Alien on earth with family attacked by humans

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for a comic about an alien on earth that is attacked by humans.

Some plot points that I (believe to) remember:

- Alien is living with his family. I think wife and one child.
- He leaves home to go somewhere. In my mind he's going to work.
- I think it's raining outside
- He is attacked by humans. I don't remember why, or what kind (civilians, military, police..)
- I think it ends badly for the alien
- The alien(s) probably have some kind of breathing device or face masks

I seem to remember that the aliens text, be it thought or speech, is written upside down or backwards (mirrored).

It must have been at least 20 years ago I read it. I think it was a short comic printed on some other comic book (possibly Marvel). I'm almost certain I read it in Swedish but I don't think it  was originally Swedish. I didn't read a lot of comics so I don't know if the story was a one off or part of a series.

My Google Fu attempts have been in vain.

Edit:

Some (small) further details:

- The alien is humanoid
- I have a vague mental image of the alien in the rain looking like a regular office worker wearing a coat and with a briefcase in hand. Not sure about this though.